# Which logfile to check for in case of warnings in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I issued an update command which gave the following output:
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 2

So I was looking for the log file which might have the details of warnings that were reported as a result of the above command.
Note: I had exited from the session so Show Warnings returns Empty Set.

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS` must be performed immediately after the query that got the warnings.  Executing any other statement will clear the list of warnings.  (No, there is no "log file" for the warnings.)

Comment: In the command line client you can also use the `\W` command to run `SHOW WARNINGS` automatically after every statement that produced warnngs. (you can turn it off again with `\w`).

See also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-warnings/ and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql-command-line-client/